# 'conclusion can be reached' - sentence structure problem

Tags: grammar

I have a problem with sentence structure, when I use 'conclusion can be reached' in this context.

I have the following sentences:

> 1. When reviewing [Name of Bank] reports, can be reached to conclusion that ...
> 2. When reviewing [Name of Bank] reports, the conclusion can be reached that ...

I am not sure, which sentence is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: The first version is not valid English. The second is "valid", but it's at least *slightly* odd, because it seems to suggest that although you *could* reach some particular conclusion, you might in fact conclude something completely different. Why not instead use *A review of [whatever] concluded/concludes that...*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is grammatically little difference between reaching a conclusion, or say, reaching the other side of the river.

> The other side of the river can be reached by bridge.

This seems clear - however:

> Can be reached the other side of the river by bridge.

Does not seem to make much sense.

In a similar way, a conclusion can be reached, but not *"can be reached a conclusion". - let alone *"can be reached to conclusion".

So your second sentence is the correct one :)